# pinescript to get weekly close price's as series from daily timeframe chart

Tags: pine-script, series, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to extract weekly close prices from **daily chart or daily secuirty-call** (request.security(syminfo.ticker , "D", screener_func())
in tradingview.

Based on timeframe change(W), i am able to get previous day close and store into array.
Its enough to get 60 weekly close prices. These 60 price values in array need to be converted into series(It can assume na beyond the 60 values). Series of these values are desired so other pine functions can be applied on the new series data.

Here the problem is, Convert array of values into series data. wkseries variable is getting only 'na' values and not elements from closewk array.

```
//@version=5
indicator("WeeklyFromDaily",overlay = true)

//series of close prices. except last day of week all other days price are na
closew2 = timeframe.change("W") ? close[1] : na

//going back to 60 weeks(approax) and collecting weekly close into array
closewk = array.new_float()
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to 60 * 5
        if not na(closew2[i]) //dont need na values
            array.push(closewk,closew2[i])

//print 3rd value in array on status line to debug array values
plot(array.size(closewk)>0? array.get(closewk,3): na, title='dataFromArray', display=display.status_line)

//THE BELOW LINE NEEDS FIX
//Convert array to series
wkseries = array.size(closewk)>0 and bar_index<62? array.get(closewk,bar_index) : na
//debug print on series values
plot(wkseries[1], title='dataFromSeries', display=display.status_line)


//Draw harizontal lines on last one weekly close price in daily chart
//debug print
line.new(bar_index, closew2[4],bar_index+10,  closew2[4], style = line.style_dashed, color = color.black, extend = extend.both)
```

Help is appreciated in the code above where comment is in capitals.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get weekly close price into an array. By the time it reaches latest bar, the array would have been filled with more than 2000 weeks of weekly close prices.

```
closew = timeframe.change("W") ? close[1] : na
var closewk = array.new_float()
if closew
    array.push(closewk,closew)
```

Here is the tricky part.
Use **last_bar_index** and **bar_index** to start reading from array for the last 60 candles. Its sufficient to get last 60 weekly close price into a series for my usecase.
So calculate array index that is needed to start getting values from array and put it into a series

```
var arridx = 0
var count = 0
if last_bar_index - bar_index == 60
    arridx := array.size(closewk) - 49 // 49 = (60-60/5+1) //5 days/week

if last_bar_index - bar_index < 60
    count := count + 1
plot(arridx+count, title='incremental array index for last 60 candles', display=display.status_line)
```

Convert the array values into series starting from last 60 daily candles

```
wkseries = array.size(closewk)>0 and (last_bar_index - bar_index) <= 60? array.get(closewk,arridx+count) : na
plot(wkseries, title='plot weekly data onto daily chart ', style=plot.style_line, display=display.all)
```

I now have a weekly close prices plotted on daily candles on a continuous basis. i.e., day0 candle/tick plotted along with recent week close, yesterday candle/tick plotted along with previous wk close, day before yesterday candle/tick plotted along with previous to previous wk close....

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is far too complex for such a task - retaining the weekly close -, so I'd suggest you choose a different one and forget about arrays.
To get the weekly close to plot on any timeframe, the simplest way is this:

```
weeklyClose = request.security("", "1W", close, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
plot(weeklyClose, "Weekly close")
```

These lines will provide you continuously with the recent weekly close.
You can tweak it depending on what you need the data for.
Similarly you can also do the following:

```
var weeklyClose = 0.0
if timeframe.change("1W")
    weeklyClose := close[1]
plot(weeklyClose, "Weekly close")
```

In the end it all comes down to your needs.

Comment: The requirement is to get data from DAILY data and not using security call that uses "W' weekly data.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what you get in both my suggestions. If you dislike security calls, go for the second option.

Comment: The second solution too doesnt work here. I am expecting a continuous series of just friday(last day of week) close values. In your solution, the fridays value is repeated 5 times till next friday data. I am looking for a solution in which the series has one tick/data for the entire 5 days(week) and not 5 data points repeated with last fridays close.
Hope i am clear with the explanation!!

Comment: That, as a data type series, is impossible to achieve in pine script. A series means the data "history" is retained of a specific variable so that you can reach past values with the history referencing operator (mySeries[1]). The history referencing operator's indices are bound to the past bars one-by-one and cannot be manipulated. Your best call in that case is to use a corresponding index in your scripts skipping n number of bars using only weekly closes once, like in a loop weeklyCloses[n*i]. That means you'd have to modify your scripts expecting weekly values to cope with that.

Comment: Yes they do. It all comes down to what you want. Crucial is the understanding of pine script series vs. arrays